# Windows shutdown/reboot notifier giving the option to delay, similar to Automatic Update

Tags: windows

I have a windows program deployed using WPKG that runs hidden to the user, and may need to reboot sometimes. In order to prevent the user from losing work, I would like a dialog box with a message, giving the logged in user the option to delay the shutdown for a bit. This is something similar to the way Automatic Update does it.

I've looked at a multitude of shutdown utilities which give the user a message, but none which give them a little control to delay the shutdown.

Comment: Ahh! you've changed the question!

Comment: Ya, specifically, I would like the logged in user sitting at the pc to delay it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *quick and dirty* option would be to use [PSSHUTDOWN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) in the [PSTOOLS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) suite from [Microsofts Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx).

One of the switches available is `-c`.  It allows the user to stop the reboot by pressing the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button.

> -c  Allows the shutdown to be aborted by the interactive user.

You could set this to loop every X minutes until the user is ready to have their machine rebooted.

---

A *neater* way to do this would be to write your own VBscript.  This could provide a snazzy dialog box offering, for example, <kbd>Yes</kbd> and <kbd>No</kbd>.  If they clicked No, it would sleep for X minutes before asking again.  This would be very easy to write.

Edit: Well, I was bored so I made the script for you.  Enjoy.

```
option explicit
on error resume next

Dim strComputer, intRebootChoice
Dim objWMIService, objOperatingSystem
Dim colOperatingSystems 

strComputer = "."

do while 1>0
 intRebootChoice = msgbox("OI, you, need to reboot.  Choose No to be asked again 1 hour",308,"Reboot incoming")
 select case intRebootChoice
  case 6
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
   Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
   For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
    ObjOperatingSystem.Reboot(1)
   Next
  case 7
   wscript.sleep(3600000)
  case else
   'shenanigans'
 end select
loop
```

Comment: Edit: Added the VBScript

Comment: So long as it helped!

Answer (score 2):

the C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe  utility seems to do the job for me.]

try the following:  **shutdown -r -t 500  -c "happy user message"**

EDIT:
The automatic updates reboot message is more of a nag screen with a time-out that has a reboot button.  Easy enough to duplicate the code for this, although you may need to ask this on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Yes, the reason why I would like this is that giving a fixed timeout seems a bit forceful. The user may need to wait for something to complete.